# How do I create will_paginate links to other pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, will-paginate

I am trying to do pagination for products.  I have:

```
   # Routes
    match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'

   # Dashboard Controller
   def index 
    @products = Product.order("id").page(params[:page]).per_page(4)
   end

   # Dashboard Index View
   h1 products
   .products
   = render @products
   = will_paginate(@products)
```

The pagination links are showing up in the dashboard index view.

Example

```
     <-- previous 1 2 3 next -->
```

But the links don't append the proper path.   The default view is localhost:3000/dashboard.
The pagination links have:

```
     http://localhost:3000/?page=2
```

For testing, if I just enter the proper path with the page params in the url bar

```
     http://localhost:3000/dashboard?page=2
```

it works fine and paginates, displaying the next set of products. My goal is to have the links have `dashboard` in the link.   I am guessing this will happen with some combination of passing options in the "will_paginate" method in the view.

I want this to happen when the user is at their root page:

```
  http://localhost:3000/dashboard
```

Comment: The question is a bit hard to read as written (preventing you from getting good answers).  Could you fill out / re-word the last three or 4 lines please?  I kind get half of what you are saying but not sure exactly what you want.  Yes the ?page=2 as a default but for when, where, etc.

Comment: Sorry.. Just revized, hopefully that is a bit more clear.

Comment: Much better.  I now revised it a fair bit too.  See what you think :)

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, that is sums it up perfect.  Now if I can only find the solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To override the will_paginate url:

```
will_paginate(@products, :params => { :controller => "dashboard", :action => "index" })
```

Or if you have named route for dashboard:

```
will_paginate(@products, :params => { :controller => dashboard_path })
```

[will paginate documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has this problem:

```
# View
# Generating pagination links for collection in another controller/action.
will_paginate @products, params: { controller: 'dashboard', action: 'index' }
```

and:

```
# routes.rb
get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index' # Before root, 2 route to the same action, Rails/will_paginate will use the first matched one in routes.rb.
root 'dashboard#index'
```